# C++ counter for selecting things from an array

Tags: c++

I have some code that randomly selects an element from an array of strings and stores that element in some other location, however I only want to be able to select the elements a certain number of times each. Here is an excerpt of my code outlining the issue. (apologies for std, but this isn't advanced enough for me to warrant not using std).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;
void setDaysOff();

string prepClasses[] = { "FREE", "1X", "4A", "4X", "5A", "5X", "6B", "6X" };

string seniorClasses[] = { "FREE", "7A", "7B", "7AB",
    "8A", "8B", "8AB", "9A", "9B", "9AB", "10D", "10T","10X", "10AX",
    "10BX", "10CX", "10Q", "11D", "11T", "11X", "11AX", "11BX", "11CX" };

string timetable[25][6][5];

int main() {

    // ZEROING
    setDaysOff();
    // END OF ZEROING

    srand ( time(NULL) );
    int RandIndex;
    int a1 = 0, a2 = 0, a3 = 0, a4 = 0, a5 = 0, a6 = 0, a7 = 0, a8 = 0, a9 = 0, a10 = 0,
        a11 = 0, a12 = 0, a13 = 0, a14 = 0, a15 = 0, a16 = 0, a17 = 0, a18 = 0, a19 = 0,
        a20 = 0, a21 = 0, a22 = 0, a23 = 0;

    for(int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
                if(timetable[i][j][k] != "0") {
                    RandIndex = rand() % (sizeof(seniorClasses)/sizeof(string));
                if(RandIndex == 0) {
                    a1++;
                    while(RandIndex == 0 && a1 > 12) {
                        RandIndex = rand() % (sizeof(seniorClasses)/sizeof(string));
                    }
                }
                else if(RandIndex == 1) {
                    a2++;
                    while(RandIndex == 1 && a2 > 8) {
                        RandIndex = rand() % (sizeof(seniorClasses)/sizeof(string));
                    }
                }
                else if(RandIndex == 2) {
                    a3++;
                    while(RandIndex == 2 && a3 > 10) {
                        RandIndex = rand() % (sizeof(seniorClasses)/sizeof(string));
                    }
                }
                else if(RandIndex == 3) {
                    a4++;
                    while(RandIndex == 3 && a4 > 8) {
                        RandIndex = rand() % (sizeof(seniorClasses)/sizeof(string));
                    }
                }
                else if(RandIndex == 4) {
                    a5++;
                    while(RandIndex == 4 && a5 > 8) {
                        RandIndex = rand() % (sizeof(seniorClasses)/sizeof(string));
                    }
                }
                else if(RandIndex == 5) {
                    a6++;
                    while(RandIndex == 5 && a6 > 10) {
                        RandIndex = rand() % (sizeof(seniorClasses)/sizeof(string));
                    }
                }
                else if(RandIndex == 6) {
                    a7++;
                    while(RandIndex == 6 && a7 > 3) {
                        RandIndex = rand() % (sizeof(seniorClasses)/sizeof(string));
                    }
                }
                else if(RandIndex == 7) {
                    a8++;
                    while(RandIndex == 7 && a8 > 5) {
                        RandIndex = rand() % (sizeof(seniorClasses)/sizeof(string));
                    }
                }
                else if(RandIndex == 8) {
                    a9++;
                    while(RandIndex == 8 && a9 > 6) {
                        RandIndex = rand() % (sizeof(seniorClasses)/sizeof(string));
                    }
                }
                else if(RandIndex == 9) {
                    a10++;
                    while(RandIndex == 9 && a10 > 5) {
                        RandIndex = rand() % (sizeof(seniorClasses)/sizeof(string));
                    }
                }
                else if(RandIndex == 10) {
                    a11++;
                    while(RandIndex == 10 && a11 > 9) {
                        RandIndex = rand() % (sizeof(seniorClasses)/sizeof(string));
                    }
                }
                else if(RandIndex == 11) {
                    a12++;
                    while(RandIndex == 11 && a12 > 3) {
                        RandIndex = rand() % (sizeof(seniorClasses)/sizeof(string));
                    }
                }
                else if(RandIndex == 12) {
                    a13++;
                    while(RandIndex == 12 && a13 > 8) {
                        RandIndex = rand() % (sizeof(seniorClasses)/sizeof(string));
                    }
                }
                else if(RandIndex == 13) {
                    a14++;
                    while(RandIndex == 13 && a14 > 4) {
                        RandIndex = rand() % (sizeof(seniorClasses)/sizeof(string));
                    }
                }
                else if(RandIndex == 14) {
                    a15++;
                    while(RandIndex == 14 && a15 > 6) {
                        RandIndex = rand() % (sizeof(seniorClasses)/sizeof(string));
                    }
                }
                else if(RandIndex == 15) {
                    a16++;
                    while(RandIndex == 15 && a16 > 6) {
                        RandIndex = rand() % (sizeof(seniorClasses)/sizeof(string));
                    }
                }
                else if(RandIndex == 16) {
                    a17++;
                    while(RandIndex == 16 && a17 > 8) {
                        RandIndex = rand() % (sizeof(seniorClasses)/sizeof(string));
                    }
                }
                else if(RandIndex == 17) {
                    a18++;
                    while(RandIndex == 17 && a18 > 12) {
                        RandIndex = rand() % (sizeof(seniorClasses)/sizeof(string));
                    }
                }
                else if(RandIndex == 18) {
                    a19++;
                    while(RandIndex == 18 && a19 > 10) {
                        RandIndex = rand() % (sizeof(seniorClasses)/sizeof(string));
                    }
                }
                else if(RandIndex == 19) {
                    a20++;
                    while(RandIndex == 19 && a20 > 7) {
                        RandIndex = rand() % (sizeof(seniorClasses)/sizeof(string));
                    }
                }
                else if(RandIndex == 20) {
                    a21++;
                    while(RandIndex == 20 && a21 > 5) {
                        RandIndex = rand() % (sizeof(seniorClasses)/sizeof(string));
                    }
                }
                else if(RandIndex == 21) {
                    a22++;
                    while(RandIndex == 21 && a22 > 10) {
                        RandIndex = rand() % (sizeof(seniorClasses)/sizeof(string));
                    }
                }
                else if(RandIndex == 22) {
                    a23++;
                    while(RandIndex == 22 && a23 > 9) {
                        RandIndex = rand() % (sizeof(seniorClasses)/sizeof(string));
                    }
                }
                    timetable[i][j][k] = seniorClasses[RandIndex];
                    cout << timetable[i][j][k] << " " << flush;
                }
                else if(timetable[i][j][k] == "0") {
                    cout << "ABS " << flush;
                }
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So, right now, the code selects data from seniorClasses and inputs them but I WANT it to after, say, picking out 10X 8 times, stop the code from selecting 10X again. Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: *apologies for std, but this isn't advanced enough for me to warrant not using std* That might be the case but you should really just avoid it.  Its a good habit to get into just using `std::`.  There are some really simple samples of code where not using `std::` does cause problems.

Comment: _Is this possible?_ Yes. Did you attempt at implementing such a feature, or should we?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Yeah, but it didn't work. I did it by writing out a bunch of if statements which ran overtime something was picked. The code found what was picked, increased a variable to do with that element, and then checked if the variable was at a certain value. This, however, meant that the code contained list after list of if statements and as many dummy variables as elements in the array. I'd prefer one counter for everything if possible?

Comment: `std::shuffle` if you can "duplicate" `seniorClasses` 8 times.

Comment: @HenrykHaniewicz So, include your solution in the question, because, currently, it looks as if you decided to outsource your problem to SO, before even _attempting_ it on your own.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius okay, edited. Please to help now?

Comment: @HenrykHaniewicz Since answer has already been posted - I will just post it in a comment, without any superfluous information: If you feel that you need that many variables, coupled with bunch of copy-pasted code - using an array, of some sort, should be the first idea that you think about.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius sorry. I'm not really a programmer. Definitely in the wrong job, but so are many people round the world :')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve this would be to add an array that increments each element by one every time you add the RandIndex item that is associated with it. Say your element 0 = Free and element 3 = 7A; when 7A is randomly selected you would increment element 3 by one.

One way this might look is such:

```
    RandIndex = rand() % (sizeof(seniorClasses)/sizeof(string));
    if (seniorClass[RandIndex]);        
      counterArray[RandIndex]++;
    if (counterArray[RandIndex] < someValue)
     timetable[i][j][k] = seniorClasses[RandIndex];
```

This is not the most elegant answer, but in your nested for loops a solution like this would work as long as your array sizes didn't get too large. If you ever wanted to export this to an application with possible array sizes approaching 100 or greater then you would have to re-work it without three nested for loops.

I haven't tried to run this code so please play with this idea and be creative because you can make this work for your current approach.

Comment: Thanks. I'll certainly give it a whirl and let you know how it works! Yeah, the array sizes in my program might increase by 1 or 2 but that's it, and I'm not planning to export any of this code so something like this will be fine!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a map to store the indices you've already been using and the number of times you've used them. This is not a complete example but it gives you an idea of what you could do.

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
map<size_t, size_t> indexCountMap; // key : index. value : number of times that index has been used

while(1)
    {
    size_t randomIndex = 0; // Generate a random index here that is within the boundary of "seniorClasses"

    auto it = indexCountMap.find(randomIndex);
    if (it == indexCountMap.end())
        indexCountMap[randomIndex] = 1; // Create the entry in the map
    else
        indexCountMap[randomIndex]++;   // Increment existing entry

    if (10 == indexCountMap[randomIndex])
        break;
    }
}
```

Also, I'm not sure why you would ever need to use a 3D string array. There are probably better ways of expressing your data in a 1D array of structures.